# Removing everything after a character, including that character in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following string in `C#`,

`my-new-field.js?role=admin`

I want to remove everything after `?` and then `?` as well so that the resultant string would be `my-new-field.js`

My string may not contain `?` every time so I need to check if the `?` is present in the string or not and then only need to remove `?` and everything after `?`.

How should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/42kjwW

```
    string test = "my-new-field.js?role=admin";
    int position = test.IndexOf("?");
    if(position >= 0) {
         test = test.Substring(0,position);
    }
```

So, substring will "cut" the string from the position 0 (very begining) to the first position of character `?`

Comment: Almost there... try the input `"?role=admin"`

Comment: @EricJ. oh man, you think in everything. You are right!!! Thanks and sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string result = "my-new-field.js?role=admin".Split('?')[0];
```

Comment: You're doing an extra string allocation here compared to the accepted answer.